# SonarQube 7.7+, Gitlab Plugin

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci

As of SonarQube 7.7 and up, the Sonar - Gitlab plugin is unavailable for compatibility reasons.

In the mean time, is there a way to fail a Gitlab CI pipeline on Quality Gate fail?

Answer (score 0):

The Sonar Scanner creates a little folder in the scan execution folder which contains a file `report-task.txt`.

```
- scan_exec_folder
| - .scannerwork
| | - report-task.txt
```

This `report-task.txt` file contains basic info about the current scan, including

- SonarQube server URL
- `ceTaskUrl` (namely, the Compute Engine Task URL of the current scan)

By `curl`ing the `ceTaskURL`, you may get the analysis status, and when the analysis is successful, the `analysisId`. (You'll almost certainly have to *wait* for the analysis to complete. You can use a `while` on the value of the `status` for example.)

Next, `curl`ing the SonarQube server URL on path

```
/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=${yourAnalysisId}
```

will return the result of the Quality Gate computation in a `json` document. If the status is `ERROR`, you know that at least one criteria has been failed.

A bit of tweaking with `grep`s and `awk`s will allow you to script this procedure and incorporate it as a task in your Gitlab CI pipeline.